# Using EMF outside an Eclipse/RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, emf, magic-draw

We have a J2EE application that we deploy to eg. tomcat. We use MagicDraw to model and generate our modelcode. We are currently looking at alternatives to MagicDraw.

I have previously used EMF:

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/

but that was inside an RCP application (handling dependencies through P2, maven/tycho).

Just a quick glance at the mvnrepository does not give too many results (of course we could upload necessary dependencies manually to our own )

http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=emf

How well does EMF work in a non RCP/OSGi application and are there any examples out there to get started?

A few resources I found:

http://www.fosslc.org/drupal/content/emf-large-scale-modeling-outside-eclipse
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t57389.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear if you are asking for a way to define models outside of an RCP app or if you simply want to work with the generated models.

It's relatively easy to work with emf from a regular Java or Java EE application. If you look for the keyword 'standalone' in the [EMF FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/FAQ) you will find some useful information.